User Assigned Managed Identity: No User Assigned or Delegated Managed Identity found for specified ClientId/ResourceId/PrincipalId
I am trying to get access token using the below code.
private static async Task<string> GetJwtTokenUsingManagedIdentity(string clientId, string tennantId)
{
    string resource = "https://management.azure.com/.default";
    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
    {
        ManagedIdentityClientId = clientId,
    });

    var tokenRequestContext = new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new[] { resource });

    var token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext);

    return token.Token;
}

But I am getting error No User Assigned or Delegated Managed Identity found for specified ClientId/ResourceId/PrincipalId. I am passing the clientId of user assigned managed Identity. Any idea what i might be missing?
On my local environment i am getting the token but based on my local account.
Below is the screenshot of Managed Identity where role has been assigned.


How did you create user managed identity?

Using the azure portal. I didn't use scripts. @Rukmini

"On my local environment i am getting the token but based on my local account" Can you please brief?

So on my local I am using visual studio for which account is same that I use in azure. So running that code on local environment gives me the token but if I decode that token user Id is same account. I think somehow on local it is using my account by default. I guess that is expected.

Managed Identity Cannot be used for local development. User managed identity is also not supported with ManagedIdentityCredential in the local environment.

That I know but when I deploy to azure.. I am getting that message @Rukmini

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

are you using system-assigned managed identity or user-assigned managed identity? if system ones, no clientId required, if user one, attach it to the azure app service.

You would usually configure DefaultAzureCredential via environment variables; https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/README.md#environment-variables Or an explicit TokenCredential class eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication/credential-chains?tabs=dac#usage-guidance-for-defaultazurecredential

@wenbo User assigned Managed identity. What do you  mean by attach to azure app service

@Amir, you need add the user-managed identity to the app service.

I created a User managed identity in the Azure Portal:


Note that: In order to use the User managed identity, you need to deploy your code to any of the Azure resource (web app, function app, VMs etc) but make sure to add the User managed identity to the same resource wherein your code resides.

Make sure to add the User managed identity to the Function app:

In my case I have created isolated Function app and deployed the below code in it:
namespace rukfunctionapp
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string clientId = "ClientID";  // Replace with your actual UMI client ID
            string tenantId = "TenantID";  // Replace with your actual tenant ID
            string jwtToken = await GetJwtTokenUsingManagedIdentity(clientId, tenantId);

            // Return the token in the response
            return new OkObjectResult($"JWT Token: {jwtToken}");
        }

        
        private static async Task<string> GetJwtTokenUsingManagedIdentity(string clientId, string tenantId)
        {
            string resource = "https://management.azure.com/.default";  
            var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
            {
                ManagedIdentityClientId = clientId,  
            });

            var tokenRequestContext = new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new[] { resource });

            
            var token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext);

            return token.Token;  
        }
    }
}


Now when I run the function in the Function app, I am able to successfully generate the token:

Decoded token:


The major piece I was missing was i did not add the managed identity to my app where my code resided, i only added UMI on the target resource which was my azure function.
Now I am able to get token. Thanks

Yeah UMI must be added where the code resides as you are passing the clientid in the code which in there in the resource. The code will not be able to access the UMI if it is not added in the resource and you are just passing the clientid.
